# mongoose $inc returns "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a like toggle using NodeJS and MongoDB(with Mongoose ORM).

When I find the specific post with `find()`, I passed it to following function which adds a new data in the Like collection.

The code looks like below:

```
...
Post.findOne({
    _id:req.params.post_id
}, function(err, post){
    if(err){
        return res.json({
            type:false, 
            message:"error finding post"
        });
    }else if(!post){
        return res.json({
            type:false, 
            message:"there is no post with the id"
        });         
    }else{
        callback(null, post); //returns post instance
    }
});

... //skipped because the code is too long

var like = new Like({
    post_id: req.params.post_id,
    user_id: req.user.id
});         
console.log(result);
like.save(function(err, updated_like){ //save the like data first
    if(err){ 
        return res.json({
            type:false,
            message:"could not save like"
        });
    } else {
        //trying to update post with the new data
        post.likes.$inc(); // PROBLEM HERE
        post.like_user_id.push(req.user.id); //no problem with this
        post.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                return res.json({
                    type:false, 
                    message:"could not like"
                });
            } 
            return res.json({
                type:true, 
                message:"liked"
            });
        });
    }
});
...
```

I am tring to implement the practice at the bottom of [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html) page.

(The example code):

```
Model.findOne({ name: 'borne' }, function (err, doc){
  doc.name = 'jason borne';
  doc.visits.$inc();
  doc.save();
});
```

My code basically looks the same, but it gives the error below:
(like_ctrl.js:90:18 is where the problem is occuring!)

```
or: undefined is not a function
or: undefined is not a function
EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NI\projects\pook\app\controllers\like_ctrl.js:90:18) 
EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NI\projects\pook\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromi
promise.js:175:45)
EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
Promise.safeEmit (C:\Users\NI\projects\pook\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\p
js:81:21)
Promise.fulfill (C:\Users\NI\projects\pook\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\pr
s:94:24)
Promise.resolve (C:\Users\NI\projects\pook\node_modules\mongoose\lib\promise.js:113:23)
model.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NI\projects\pook\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1569:39)
next_ (C:\Users\NI\projects\pook\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\hooks-fixed\hooks.js:89:3

EventEmitter.fnWrapper (C:\Users\NI\projects\pook\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\hooks-fi
ks.js:171:15)
EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NI\projects\pook\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromi
promise.js:175:45)
EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
Promise.safeEmit (C:\Users\NI\projects\pook\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\p
js:81:21)
Promise.fulfill (C:\Users\NI\projects\pook\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\pr
s:94:24)
p1.then.then.self.isNew (C:\Users\NI\projects\pook\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:254:27)

newTickHandler (C:\Users\NI\projects\pook\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\pro
:229:18)
process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
=============
```

What did i do wrong here?

add to this,

I have post schema which looks like

```
var postSchema  = new Schema({
    title: {type:String},
    content: {type:String},
    likes:{type:Number, default:0},
    like_user_id:[{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Like'}]
});
```

this and like schema looks like below:

```
var likeSchema  = new Schema({
    user_id: Schema.ObjectId,
    post_id: {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Post'},
    created_at:{type:Date, default:Date.now}
});
```

Comment: `$inc` isn't a function, it's an operator used as a key in a query

Comment: @adeneo so the manual is wrong? http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html

Comment: No, the docs are most likely correct, but they are using `$inc` on a returned marker, not on the model itself.

Comment: Actually, looking at your code, I'm not quite sure where `post` is coming from, so I have no idea what it is in that context ?

Comment: @adeneo I returned instance of `post` on the topmost block of code when i used `findOne` method. as you see in the bottom block, push and save just works fine, indicating that `post` instance is successfully returned...

Comment: Try logging `post.likes` and see what you have then

Comment: @KeonKim the documentation you're referring to is based on Mongoose 2.x, but the current version (and probably the version you're actually using) is 4.x. Documentation for that version can be found [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html).

Comment: @adeneo i posted solution below, thanks for helping!

Comment: @robertklep  i posted solution below, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was looking at Mongoose 2.7 docs and $inc prototype on the returned instance is no longer supported in Mongoose 4.

However, there was no relevant code in the new documentation that replaces the $inc.

So I found my own way and the solution was shockingly simple.

just do `post.likes++;` instead of `post.likes.$inc();`